# Using NativeCall to call the C fn `erf` gets more precise output than `erf` in C

Tags: c, printf, raku, rakudo, nativecall

I have written a Raku script to call `erf` function in C standard library:

```
use NativeCall;
sub erf(num64) returns num64 is native { * };

say [0.5,1,2,3,4,-0.9].map: {erf($_.Num)};
```

The output of this script

```
(0.5204998778130465 0.8427007929497149 0.9953222650189527 0.9999779095030014 0.9999999845827421 -0.7969082124228322)
```

matches with the output from C for all values `[0.5,1,2,3,4,-0.9]` except `4`.

For `4` the C outputs `1.000000` while Raku gives `0.9999999845827421`.

To test the output for `4` in C, run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h> // Including header file for printf function
#include <math.h>  // Including header file for erf function

int main (){

  double param, result;
  param = 4.0;
  result = erf(param);
  printf("erf (%f) = %f\n", param, result);
  return 0;
}
```

Any idea what's going on? I need to output `1.0` from Raku too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're comparing apples with oranges.

```
use NativeCall;
sub erf(num64) returns num64 is native { * };

say .fmt("%f") for [0.5,1,2,3,4,-0.9].map: {erf($_.Num)}

0.520500
0.842701
0.995322
0.999978
1.000000
-0.796908
```

You're using `printf` in C, if you use `.fmt` (the easier way to say `sprintf` in Raku), then you'd also get `1.0`.

Answer (score 9):

For the C code, change `%f` to `%.99g` to show more digits. This reveals `erf(4)` returns 0.9999999845827420852373279558378271758556365966796875.

`%f` requests six digits after the decimal point. The value is rounded to fit that format. `%.numberf` requests `number` digits after the decimal point and always used the “fixed” format. `%.numberg` requests `number` significant digits and uses a a “general” format that switches to exponential notation when appropriate.

For the Raku code, if you want output of “1.0” or “1.000000”, you will need to apply some formatting request to the output. I do not practice Raku, but a brief search shows Raku has `printf`-like features you can use, so requesting the `%f` format with it should duplicate the C output.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another version building on @Eric's explanation about precision:

```
my $fmt = '%.6f';
printf [$fmt ~ ' '] x 5 ~ $fmt ~ "\n", [0.5,1,2,3,4,-0.9].map: {erf($_.Num)};
```

`[$fmt ~ ' '] x 5 ~ $fmt ~ "\n"` builds the format string `"%.6f %.6f %.6f %.6f %.6f %.6f\n"`

Output

```
0.520500 0.842701 0.995322 0.999978 1.000000 -0.796908
```

Or even more [raku](/questions/tagged/raku) as proposed by [raiph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1077672/raiph), using the *infix* operator [`xx`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/xx):

```
printf "{'%.6f' xx 6} \n", [0.5,1,2,3,4,-0.9].map: {erf($_.Num)};
```

Comment: Nice follow up. FYI `$fmt xx 6 ~ "\n"` builds the same format string. See [`xx`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/xx) and [`List.Str`](https://docs.raku.org/type/List#method_Str). Likewise `"{$fmt xx 6} \n"`. See ["interpolate Raku code from within the string, using curly braces:"](https://docs.raku.org/language/quoting#Interpolation:_qq#:~:text=interpolate%20Raku%20code%20from%20within%20the%20string,%20using%20curly%20braces).

Comment: @raiph Great! I added that one to the answer!